# Optimality in Clustering algorithms and an Optimality guaranteed clustering algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, optimal, deterministic

So there are lots of clustering algorithms with different characteristics. What I am interested in now is a clustering algorithm which guarantees to find the optimal clustering result (if exists). And consequently, the algorithm would be deterministic.

E.g. DBSCAN is deterministic but is it guaranteed to find the optimal clustering solution? For k-means, this doesn't apply since it is non-deterministic and it can get stuck in local minima.

1. So is there a clustering algorithm which guarantees to find the optimal solution?
2. And are clustering algorithms classified by their "Finding optimal solution" characteristic? If a clustering algorithm X is deterministic, does it mean that it finds the best clustering that exists?
   Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "the optimal solution"? Different methods imply different concepts of what a good clustering is, so they will find different solutions, which often all have their own merits. There is no such thing as a general definition of what an "optimal clustering" means. You may want to read this: https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.02059

Comment: To find the global optimum of a *given objective function* (such as the k-means one) is a different issue, see your other question. But for clustering in general there is no generally accepted best objective function.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answers @Lewian

Answer (score 1):

There is no general efficient algorithm that gives you globally optimal solution given a general optimisation problem (even narrowed down to clustering, but that is an optimisation problem as well), as also mentioned in the comments.